# RxJS reduce function value param return whole arr instead of normal reduce function do

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am developing Angular app right now, and wanna call a service that return Array of Users (Assumed)

The response of the service is like

```
[{id: 1, name: 'foo'}, 
 {id: 2, name: 'bar'}]
```

I want to calculate each item based on previous object, so I come out to use REDUCE function to replace all the objects in the array, and the ITEM object just return all the array to me instead of one, so I try return last item to inspect the result like this.

```
of(users).pipe(
  reduce((arr, item)=>item, [])
).subscribe(r=>console.log(r))
// [{id: 1, name: 'foo'}, {id: 2, name: 'bar'}]
```

But I try to use normal reduce function, it returns

```
users.reduce((arr, item)=>item), [])
// {id: 2, name: 'bar'}
```

Here is my example on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-e97p4c?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: What you are expecting as result?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want to do. Maybe you don't want to emit the array as whole and rather reemit each item separately? Like with `from(users)` instead of `of(users)`

Comment: @imvpn22 Just like martin mentioned, because I want to modify each item in the array, but rxjs reduce function response with whole array instead of the element, so I  can't access the item in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because RxJS returns value over time. On the other hand, array is traversing the array value. Therefore, when you use RxJS, returning `item` will result in the whole array object being returned.

it will be different if you have value overtime. the below code display how your code look like in array.

```
interval(1000).pipe(
 take(2),
 map(x=>users[x]),
 reduce((arr,item)=>item)
).subscribe(x=>console.log('l',x))
```